How to reverse a Validator filter?
I'm working with a ComboBox and depending on the current CMB item, a filter is applied to a lineedit. I can define the input of numbers only
lineedit.setValidator(QDoubleValidator(0, 1000000, 2, notation=QDoubleValidator.StandardNotation))

But I want to reverse this filter and return the input of any character. How do I do that?

setValidator(None).
